# Time series forecasting with SARIMAX model

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, sarimax

I am trying to build a SARIMAX model for time series forecasting. I am not able to figure out what the period of seasonality should be. My data is daily data (exculding weekends) of stock prices for past 5 years. I have resampled it to weekly data.

the seasonal_decompose shows seasonality with different seasonal period values - 12,52

i am not able to find out what shall be the value of period in the following code

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(data['Close'], model='additive', period=?)
decomposition.plot()
plt.show()
```

i also did the ADFuller test and found that the number of lags is 14 and hence decided to go with period=14 in the seasonal_decompose

is this the right approach? if not, then what?

also, once i have decided what the seasonal period will be, suppose 14, then 14 will also be used while differencing, right?

for ex - will 14 be used here?

```
data['seasonal'] = data['Close'] - data['Close'].shift(14)
```

please help,

Thank you

i went with period = 14 because that was the number of lags while doing the ADfuller test